# Почему не удается восстановить базу данных из файла резервной копии?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, dump

Создал файл резервной копии mydb1 с помощью команды mysqldump:

```
mysqldump -u root mydb1 > C:\"DB dumps\mydb1.sql"
```

Удалил БД mydb1

И теперь хочу восстановить данные:

```
mysql -u root -D mydb1 < C:\"DB dumps\mydb1.sql"
```

Выдает ошибку: Unknown database 'mydb1'
Почему так? Что делать?

Comment: Потому что сперва нужно создать базу, в которую резервная копия будет восстанавливаться

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, теперь работает. Если хотите, напишите это как ответ, и я отмечу как решение вопроса